# Calendar View of a Field Collections and Contextual Filters

Tags: views

I've clicked my way into a corner. So I have a Field Collection called Performance Dates that is embedded to a Content Type of Performance that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to put this into a calendar view, listing all dates (the field collection) from a single performance (the Performance content type).

[image]

Since Entity Host ID is not offered as a contextual filter, I was thinking to create a contextual filter on the Field Collection's ID.

[image]
[image]

My question: If I am going about this the right way, is there a way to return an array of IDs here much like using SQL `where id in (x, y, z)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I started out creating a View from a Template.

[image]

Then, I decided to use a module called [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) which is super easy to configure.

[image]

And here we go!

There is still some configurations to set in place but for the most part, this issue has been solved.

[image]